# Find element by position using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

My selenium driver finds about 13 li elements. However, the following does not work, giving element not found error:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[0]')
```

But, this works correctly:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li')[0]
```

I thought these are the same, although I would prefer the first approach to work. What is going on here?

Comment: Quite simple, XPath indexing is not zero-based. Python indexing is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is zero-indexed, but [XPath is one-indexed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates):

> The first position is 1.

As a result, the following are equivalent:

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li')[0]
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//li)[1]')
```

Comment: Not quite. The XPath should be `(//li)[1]`. Without the parens, it selects every `li` that is the first `li` child of its parent.